# Weird circles and line when creating polygon in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro

When I create a polygon with the tool "Create" in ArcGIS Pro, weird circles and lines are created as seen in the screenshot. Does anyone know how to deactivate them? It is annoying because if snapping is activated, it will snap to these lines and circles.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try deactivating the grid using the Grid button at the bottom of the Map view:

[image]

Comment: Did not work unfortunately.